# Replacing Special Characters with regex - C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation, user-input

I am trying to remove special characters (with a few exceptions) from a string by using [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx). I am using the NET framework v4.0 and my code is the following:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^\w !@$*-_.]", "",
                                 RegexOptions.None);
```

However, during testing, I have noticed that on top of the characters listed above, it is not replacing others like [ ] \ or /. I thought these would be caught by the regular expression and it concerns me that there might be others that are not caught either.

Any advice to figure out the cause and how to solve it would be very appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you trying to allow `!`, `$`, and `*` in addition to the word, period, hypen, and `@` specified by the original MSDN example?  I see you've modified the regex from that example.

Comment: As @JohnWeldon has said, your example differs from the website example you posted. What are the exceptions you want? Also - this website is useful for testing our Regex expressions - http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Hi, John. Yes, I am allowing characters "!@$*-_." (without the quotes), plus the empty space. The problem is that it is not only allowing those, but also some more that I have found during testing (like "[ ] \  /", again, without the quotes). I would want it to allow only the characters I list, and no others.

Comment: The hyphen needs to be last or escaped, otherwise it treats the two sides of the hypen as a range.

Comment: John, it looks like that was exactly the problem. As soon as I escaped it, it also replaced the [ ] \ / characters (which might have been within that range). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version allows the three additional symbols you seem to be trying to add:

```
Regex.Replace(
    @"a!s$d*f[a\s/df]a_s.d-f",
    @"[^\w\.!$*@-]",
    "",
    RegexOptions.None)
```

Yields

```
a!s$d*fasdfa_s.d-f
```

The problem with your modification is that it was allowing all characters between `*` and `_`

You could rewrite your example as:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^\w !@$*\-_.]", "",
                             RegexOptions.None);
```

Notice the escaping of the hyphen

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much!